# Как узнать размер спрайта в unity?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Нужно очень точно измерить размер спрайта в unity, спрайт создан на основе встроенных функций unity (просто квадрат), и есть ли способ поместить значение размера спрайта в переменную в коде. в параметре scale значение 7, и вообще, почему в профессиональном движке нет элементарного показателя size? Еще, сколько пикселей составляет одна единица в unity? Спасибо

Comment: Размер спрайта ровно такой, каким вы его задали отобразить. Какая у вас используется проекция, ортогональная или перспективная?

Comment: Я имею ввиду какой размер спрайта в unity, и сколько пикселей составляет одна единица в unity. Про проекцию я вообще не слышал

Comment: В unity есть своя единица (ее можно увидеть в показателе transform)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поместить размер обьекта в переменную:

```
  private Vector3 sizeXYZ = obj.localScale;
```

Чтобы поместить одно значение из размера обьекта/спрайта:

```
  private float sizeX = obj.localScale.x; //вместо x можно ввести y или z
```

Чтобы узнать размер спрайта:

```
  private Vector2 sizeXY = new Vector2(obj.localScale.x,obj.localScale.y);
```

Одна единица в юнити не составляет определённое количество пикселей, оно зависит от размера камеры, меша обьекта, типа камеры (перспективная или ортографическая), и т.д

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема в том что нужно спрайт сдвинуть на его же размер, я же не буду его на значение scale менять

Comment: @Said если ты пытаешься сделать пиксельную игру, где спрайт двигается на 1 его пиксель (или больше), то просто подбирай рандомные числа пока не будет нормальный результат, а если ты хочешь поменять позицию спрайта, на его же размер, то тебе как раз надо будет менять его на Scale по X